# Cannot update API.AI oAuthLinking.authorizationUrl parameter in agent.json

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I have an API.AI agent that I'm using to connect to Google Assistant.

At some point, I changed the authorization URI in my implicit grant oauth flow to a new domain. I've tried to update the authorizationUrl parameter in the agent.json file, but this hasn't worked.

1) There appears to be no where in the API.AI UI that allows this parameter to be modified

2) When I try Export & Import -> Export as Zip -> Edit parameters in agent.json -> Restore from Zip, the process seems to complete successfully, but the parameter (as verified by another zip export) is unchanged.

I believe this is preventing a successful integration with the Google Assistant service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify these parameters at the [actions console](http://console.actions.google.com) account linking section. See [this page](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/account-linking#step_2_enable_account_linking) for more detail.

Comment: The authorization URL appears correctly in the AoG interface, but the action package on API.AI still shows the old URL, which I suspect is causing problems.

Comment: The one in the AoG interface should override the one you see in API.AI action package